# How to access Symfony 3.4 object values from Request::createFromGlobals()

Tags: javascript, php, symfony-3.4

I am trying to use Symfony 3.4 components in a legacy project. There is a form that has two fields city and state. I want to send those two fields to a class method. So, I built an intermediate PHP file to pass the data to using javascript. The form and javascript are here.

```
     <form class="form-inline" id="addpharmacies">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city" ><?php print xlt("City");?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="state"><?php print xlt("State");?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
let f = document.getElementById('addpharmacies');
f.addEventListener('submit', importPharm);

function importPharm() {
top.restoreSession();
let city = document.getElementById("city").value;
let state = document.getElementById("state").value;
if (city.length === 0 || state.length ===0) {
    alert("City and state must both be filled out") 
    return false;
}
let body = {"city": city, "state": state};
let req = new Request('pharmacyHelper.php', {method: "POST", body: body});
fetch(req)
    .then(response=> {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.json()
        } else {
            throw new Error("Bad response from the server");
        }
    })
    .then(json => {
        alert(json) // Not a great UI experience
    })
```

}

As you can see that I am using a listener to submit the form by way of the javascript function importPharm. The javascript gets the data from the form via a  getElementById call to city and state fields.

A request is created and the data is passed into the request and the helper file is called to pass the data. I have verified that something is being sent to the helper file. But I can see is [object Object] when I do a getContent().

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
 $content = $request->getContent();
 file_put_contents("api.txt", $content);
```

When I try:

```
    $request->request->get('city','');
```

I get nothing. I have tried every combination I could find on the [Symfony Site](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html)

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you haven't specified any headers clarifying your content-type so it's ambiguous for Symfony to detect your content type and map them to the [Parameter Bag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php) (although it displays the content body) , try adding the :

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

header and send your form inputs as form-data and try again , else you will need to **[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** the content body and deal with it as an array or \StdClass object .

**N.B** : Using form-data your request would look like this

```
let body = "city="+city+"&state="+state;
let req = new Request('pharmacyHelper.php', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-url-encoded', 
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },body: body});
fetch(req).then(response=> {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        return response.json()
                    } else {
                        throw new Error("Bad response from the server");
                    }
                })
                .then(json => {
                    alert(json) // Not a great UI experience
                })
```

Comment: Salama96 Thanks for your reply. Adding the header did not make the problem go away. The removal of the {} from the body made the body just text instead of an object. Which was fine because I could progress past this point. I tested with and without the header. Then I tested with and without the curly braces. It was the {} that creates the object in the receiving code that I can't parse.